# Grails: ClassNotFoundException for GrantedAuthoritiesMapper with spring-security-core 1.2.7.3 when running as WAR

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working on a grails app that uses spring security with CAS and LDAP.  It's configuration is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881168/715608).  When I run with `grails run-app`, everything works fine, but when I deploy the WAR to tomcat (or call `grails run-war`), I get the following exception:

```
2013-10-16 11:19:47,658 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
    ... 7 more
2013-10-16 11:19:47,658 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper
    ... 7 more
```

This used to work on Tomcat until I added some dependencies that had `spring-security-core 3.1.4` transitive dependencies.  I had to exclude those transitive dependencies to get it to run (with `grails run-app`), which left `spring-security-core 3.0.7` on the classpath, but it won't run as a WAR.  When I remove those dependencies, the app runs as a WAR fine, but I need the functionality in those dependencies.  The only thing I can think of is that I need `spring-security-core 3.1.4`.

Is there a version of the grails spring security plugin that uses `spring-security-core 3.1.x` (preferably 3.1.4)?

Comment: There's a new version of the plugin, but it uses a RC of Spring Security 3.2.

Comment: yes, but there isn't a corresponding new version of `spring-security-cas`, and I haven't been able to get the new core and ldap plugins to work with the old cas plugin.