# Grails and CAS Basic Setup

Tags: spring, grails, cas

Trying to setup a simple Grails app with basic CAS protection.

First, I'm having trouble telling what the differences are between cas-plugin versus spring-security-core and spring-security-cas...when would I use one versus the other?

In my test I have the following configured:

In BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
        ...
...     
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
        compile ":spring-security-cas:1.0.5"
    }
```

In Config.groovy...I don't know what I need. Different docs refer to different values, but here's what I've got so far:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/login/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/logout/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = 'http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/' + appName + '/j_spring_cas_security_check'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://cas2.mydomain.com:8443/cas'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/' + appName + '/secure/receptor'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = 'https://cas2.mydomain.com:8443/cas/logout?url=http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/' + appName + '/'
```

Now when I browse to my app, I get forwarded to the CAS login page...after entering credentails I get a browser error page:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

and the cas.log says:

```
INFO: Server startup in 21570 ms
2013-10-31 11:28:05,178 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <Beginning ticket cleanup.>
2013-10-31 11:28:05,180 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <0 tickets found to be removed.>
2013-10-31 11:28:05,180 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <Finished ticket cleanup.>
2013-10-31 11:28:10,088 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - <Setting path for cookies to: /cas/>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,498 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated [username: myusername]>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,518 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Resolved principal myusername>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,518 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler@4e1e6e1f authenticated myusername with credential [username: myusername].>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,523 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: myusername]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [username: myusername]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 31 11:28:16 EDT 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx150.30
SERVER IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
=============================================================

>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,527 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: myusername]
WHAT: TGT-1-76m7jUyKI7pguovcGWmJqKOsbpqp6wW2yj3dTCNOCtb65MKpTH-cas2
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 31 11:28:16 EDT 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx150.30
SERVER IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
=============================================================

>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,533 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-1-rvDgqEvGQDeljEeVf5rM-cas2] for service [http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/j_spring_cas_security_check] for user [myusername]>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,533 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: myusername
WHAT: ST-1-rvDgqEvGQDeljEeVf5rM-cas2 for http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/j_spring_cas_security_check
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 31 11:28:16 EDT 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx150.30
SERVER IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
=============================================================

>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,703 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed to authenticate [callbackUrl: http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/secure/receptor]>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,704 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [callbackUrl: http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/secure/receptor]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [callbackUrl: http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/secure/receptor]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 31 11:28:16 EDT 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
SERVER IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
=============================================================

>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,705 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: myusername
WHAT: error.authentication.credentials.bad
ACTION: PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Oct 31 11:28:16 EDT 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
SERVER IP ADDRESS: xxx.xx0.79
=============================================================

>
2013-10-31 11:28:16,706 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController] - <TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/secure/receptor]>
org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketCreationException: error.authentication.credentials.bad
        at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody6(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody7$advice(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:57)
        at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController.handleRequestInternal(ServiceValidateController.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:128)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:57)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1810)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This bit:

```
2013-10-31 11:28:16,703 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed to authenticate [callbackUrl: http://cas2.mydomain.com:8085/rss_03/secure/receptor]>
```

seems to be the issue...my credentials are good so it looks like something is still missing in config...any ideas...?

**UPDATE:**

Put the app under SSL, and to Config.groovy, to the interceptUrlMap Added:

```
'/secure/receptor': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
```

Now the cas.log shows what looks to be similar looping (back and forth between cas and the app) to what I was getting before, except no errors...eventually it stops and the browser again shows:

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859654/using-spring-security-in-grails-with-cas-and-ldap/17870147#17870147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow unauthenticated access to your receptor.  Try this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/login/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/logout/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/secure/receptor': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],  // <- allows CAS to contact the receptor
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I had to put the app under SSL too...I was still getting errors without it. I updated my post above...the ticket granting/validating is still looping :(

Comment: I also found that if I added spring-security-ldap and did the config for pulling roles from LDAP that this looping went away...but this isn't really a solution. Some of our apps we would want dependent on LDAP roles/groups, others are accessed by everyone with valid credentials.