# Redirect loop with Grails Spring Security CAS plugin

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I am working with a project involving CAS server works with other Spring-based projects using Single-Sign On (SSO), but I am receiving a redirect loop involving the Grails spring-security-cas plugin (version: ":spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1"). I've looked at the [plugin's documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-cas/docs/manual/guide/index.html). I know CAS redirect questions appear common, but I have yet to find a posting related to this type of situation. I am new-ish to the Grails and CAS worlds, so thank you in advance for any push in the right direction.

Accessing a secured page on the grails app initially redirects to the CAS server login page correctly, with the appropriate service parameter: https:// example.com:8443/cas/login?service=http:// example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check

The **problem** occurs after the user logs in successfully and CAS redirects back to the service. The j_spring_cas_security_check in the grails app is redirecting back to the https://example.com:8443/cas login page, which sees the TGC and redirects back to the service j_spring_cas_security_check page, which redirects ad infinitum [until the browser gives the redirect loop error]. It also looks like new service tickets are getting created each iteration.

My Config.groovy has:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = /login
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = http://example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = https://example.com:8443/cas
# we aren't using cas with proxy
# logout details not shown here
```

Unsuccessful attempts already tried based on other questions/answers:

- I don't think the issue is with the cas server: when I go directly to another of the projects already using CAS they detect the ticket cookie and login just fine without the user having to authenticate again.
- The SSL certificate is self-signed and already added to Java's cacert store. No SSLHandshake or Certificate-related exceptions, etc. occur.
- It's not a bad credentials or proxy situation like [question 19710841](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710841/grails-and-cas-basic-setup), but I've tried adding the /j_spring_cas_security_check to the Annotation staticRules anyways but get the same loop.

The cas server's logs include:

```
=============================================================
WHO: [username: sampleuser]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [username: sampleuser]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Fri Jan 03 23:52:41 GMT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
SERVER IP ADDRESS: example.com
=============================================================
=============================================================
WHO: [username: sampleuser]
WHAT: TGT-24-Rttmt5i5raWcV1Z5wZavVopigQc4xeIckEUfMKdG3EwEzI3LUI-cas.service
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Fri Jan 03 23:52:41 GMT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
SERVER IP ADDRESS: example.com
=============================================================

INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-77-cneJOIwmnoOdKqkscaiy-cas.service] for service [http://example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check] for user [sampleuser]>

####### FIRST ITERATION OF LOOP BELOW #############

=============================================================
WHO: sampleuser
WHAT: ST-77-cneJOIwmnoOdKqkscaiy-cas.service for http://example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Fri Jan 03 23:52:41 GMT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
SERVER IP ADDRESS: example.com
=============================================================
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-77-cneJOIwmnoOdKqkscaiy-cas.service
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Fri Jan 03 23:52:41 GMT 2014
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: example.com
=============================================================

DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - <Placing service in FlowScope: http://example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check>
INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-78-6qsbaVNNOess4VhGOQE4-cas.service] for service [http://example.com:8080/grailsapp/j_spring_cas_security_check] for user [sampleuser]>

####### SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED and SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATED LOOP CONTINUES A FEW MORE TIMES BEFORE BROWSER GIVES UP #############
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that in the Grails client I did not create a userDetailsService. I implemented a custom class within Grails' services folder (See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html):

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    // Required methods here
}
```

then referenced this in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to overwriting `UserDetailsService` I had to configure `filterProcessesUrl` in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.filterProcessesUrl = "/user/login" // same as uri part of serviceUrl
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://yoursite.com/user/login"
```

for CasAuthenticationFilter to kick in after authentication on CAS. Following are source code reference links:

You can also look at the source for [CasAuthenticationFilter.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-cas/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/cas/web/CasAuthenticationFilter.java?av=f)
 see the `serviceTicketRequest` and `super.requiresAuthentication` methods.