# grails 3.0.0 I can not create an application

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I just downloaded Grails 3.0.0  [(hoping to see my problems with CAS magically disappearing ;) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393282/q-grails2-4-cas-and-the-infamous-redirect-loop)
I installed it under windows and then:

```
D:\GrailsProjects> grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.0.0
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_51
```

and then:

```
D:\IntelliJProjects>grails create-app helloworld
| Error Command not found create-app
Did you mean: create-script or create-taglib or create-unit-test?
```

also clean and compile don't work

What am I missing?

Comment: Try upgrading to 3.0.1

Comment: I had the exact same problem, *no idea* what the cause was, but on OS X I opened up a new terminal, used GVM to switch to 3.0.1 (I have 2.5.0 as default) and it started working. Go figure...

Comment: Still no joy for me:

`D:\>cd TEMP  

| Grails Version: 3.0.1  
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3  
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_51  
D:\TEMP>grails create-app helloworld  
| Error Command not found create-app  
Did you mean: create-script or create-taglib or create-unit-test?`    


My %PATH% contains among the other things: D:\Programs\grails-3.0.1\bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok that was trivial (and rather stupid).
In the "project directory" among other projects there was a directory called grails-app, probably leftover of some porting. This caused the create-app to fail. Removed the directory everything works fine.