# Listing plugin updates for new Grails 3.0 application

Tags: grails, plugins, updates, grails-3.0

A lot has changed for **Grails 3.0**.  How do run `list-plugin-updates` for an application?

The command used to work for me but now results in an error.

```
$ grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.0.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_45
$ uname -sr
Darwin 14.3.0
$
$ grails list-plugin-updates
| Error Command not found list-plugin-updates
Did you mean: list-plugins or plugin-info or test?
```

The documentation implies the command should still work:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/list-plugin-updates.html

Comment: Possibly related to: *grails 3.0.0 I can not create an application* at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29395785/1553812

Comment: There's a lot in the 3.0 docs that needs to be removed or reworked since 3.0 is very different from earlier versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins for Grails 3.0 have moved over to Bintray:

- https://bintray.com/grails/plugins

Grails now uses Gradle for dependency resolution and the way plugins are identified has changed.

Example of using the LESS plugin under Grails 3.0:

- http://davydotcom.com/blog/2015-01-29-grails-3-0-0-m1-asset-pipeline-tips-tricks

It seems the `list-plugin-updates` command is no longer applicable.